# Angular 5 how to modify ngx datatable component and run it

Tags: angular, npm, ngx-datatable

I made an angular project, and I am using ngx-datatable.

Now I have a problem with ngx-datatable, so I would like to debug the code, but I am noob on how to do this.

I installed @swimlane ngxdatatable, and I am writing a row directly into the file, for example I wrote the following in the file :
node_module/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/src/body.component.ts

I wrote a simple console.log("saaaaaaaaaa") on the nginit just to check if I can modify the source.

But the console log does not show it.

I think I need to deploy the update, but I don't know how.

To make the question more general, how can I modify an installed component via npm directly in my project?

---

i think i find the how to do :

- make a fork of the project
- clone the fork project
- modify the fork project locally (here i got a question, you can see
  belowe)
- build the fork project locally
- commit the modify
- use the new modify project and in case request a pull the the
  developer of the component.

what i need now is the undstanding to how debug the component, when i make ng serve and start the project i can debug all the example of the project but i can not debug the file of the component, file like body.component.ts etc. any idea on what i miss for debugging ?
Naturally if i modify body.component.ts i can see my update to the code. but i not like to debug whit console.log so i like to use the browser debug plugin for this.

Answer (score 0):

> May be this link will help. Any clarification needed let me know.                   https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/demo/basic/inline.component.ts

Comment: that is just an example of ngxdatatable not what i wanted, however tnx.